# Show processes that run on the system, but on all computers, not just on my computer

Tags: java, javafx

These instructions show "operations" that run on the my system, but these instructions are not run on other systems.
So How can i use "ProcessHandler" or any other way for instructions to run on "all systems" (to be a solution for all systems that the application will run on).

Or in General:
How Can i use "ProcessHandler" to appear "all Process" that run in my System and another System ?,
( when I take these instructions and run them on another system, I want to work )
I want these instructions to run on different computers with different system,How can i make that ?.

```
            public void proc1(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {        
            try 
            {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(tt1.getText().replace(':', '-')+".txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;
            String proc="";
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            proc=proc+"\n"+line;
            }
            showMessageDialog(null,proc);    
            reader.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
            showMessageDialog(null, "No Processes to view");
            }
            }
             //get Process
              s="";
              try {
              String line;
              Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
              (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
              BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));           
              while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
              //System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
              s=s+"\n"+line;
              }
              input.close();
              } 
              catch (Exception err) {
               err.printStackTrace();
               }
```

Comment: what if other system is linux?

Comment: This is exactly my question, I want to change the instructions in the code to be able to implement it on any other system, but I did not know How can i make This.

Comment: by `any other` system, do you also mean [ibm/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360) ?

Comment: I mean Just like "Windows" or "Linux" or "Mac"...

Comment: which [linux distributives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions) you're targeting?

Comment: maybe all or this:
Red Hat
Debian
Novell Suse
Gentoo
Slackware 
or all windows systems

Comment: ok, then read manuals about every system how to get list of running processes, then read any book about client server programming, you need to run some client on every host which will be able to send information to you about running processes

Comment: Windows also ? 
Can you send links to benefit from it?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: and windows and macos as well, you have client for windows already

Comment: And "ProcessHandler"  doesn't help me with this thing, right?

Comment: I guess you're not talking about process of a remote machine, but about running the application on various platforms. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's my intention, I want my app that contains these instructions to work on different systems.

Comment: `ProcessHandler` is used to launch process from java code, not to get actual processes

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
And if i want to use ProcessHandler to launch process from Java Code, How Can use it ?
And in the other side , to get the actual operations, I have to follow what you said earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [ProcessHandle#allProcesses()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#allProcesses()) can help you there (thanks to @slaw for the pointer).

If it doesn't provide the information you need and unless you find a 3rd party library which solves this for all your supported platforms, you will likely need the following steps:

- define an interface which abstracts the platform-specific code (e.g. provide a method `getTaskListCommand`)
- write an implementation of this interface for each supported platform (e.g. implement the `getTaskListCommand` for Windows with the command you're currently using: `System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe"`)
- load the implementation which matches the platform, e.g. with the help of [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

Comment: Can you send links to benefit from it?
Or could the three points be explained in detail?

Comment: @Mario Are you asking how to list running processes on the _host_ machine only? If so, and if you're using Java 9+, see [`ProcessHandle#allProcesses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#allProcesses()). Otherwise, if you want to query _remote_ computers then there's nothing in standard Java, as far as I know.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, I ask how to list the running processes on the system the application is running on.
For example, the project will run on my system and my system is Windows 32, but if I run the project on Windows32 or Linux  system it will not work.

Comment: @Mario Then the method I linked to in my previous comment should work for you, provided you're using Java 9+.

Comment: @Slaw Ok,Thank you for your answer .I will use it